# exception handling in C# when try catch block is not provided

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which gets an exception thrown, and my code in not within  a try-catch block. Is there any way i can get the exception details without wrapping it within a try-catch block?

Please help.

Comment: How can it not be "available" to you?

Comment: Your app will die if you don't catch an exception anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit CodeProject article [Managing Unhandled Exceptions in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2949/Managing-Unhandled-Exceptions-in-NET)

Hope it should Help.

Answer (score 0):

In that case your exceptions will not be handled , just thrown. The best way to avoid them would be to check all possible exception sources, and avoid them, for example where a null posibility occurs check if the method returns null first.

So its either you handle an exception or you dont handle it, no inbetweens.

Answer (score 0):

A Try/Catch statement IS available to you and yo should use it when handling exceptions. It depends on the task you are performing as to which Exceptions you can possibly catch.

You can do something like this as an example:-

```
Try
{
   // Perform Task
}
Catch(Exception x)
{
  MessageBox.Show(x.message);
}
Catch(ArgumentException x)
{
  MessageBox.Show(x.message);
}
```

There is no reason as to why you cannot perform this check.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wanted to know , like which part either linker or CLR or anything else handles exception.

Comment: You must go from the most *specific* exception you want to handle to the most general. In this case, `ArguementException` won't be caught by that particular catch statement, it'll be caught at the general `Exception` one. Have not downvoted it, since it still answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

if a method need to return string variable,but we do not use try catch block,you can like this:

delare a string variable(now we named it sRetString) for return.

```
if(condition1)

   sRetString="abc";

else 

   sRetString="edf";

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sRetString))

   return string.empty;

else

   return sRetString;
```

**But I think you had better  use try catch block for catch some unexpected expection.**